# Tuple of Tensors

Tags: pytorch, tuples, tensor

I recently asked one part of this question. I am building a chatbot, and there is a function that makes the problems. The function is given below:

```
def variable_from_sentence(sentence):
  vec, length = indexes_from_sentence(sentence)
  inputs = [vec]
  lengths_inputs = [length]
  if hp.cuda:
    batch_inputs = Variable(torch.stack(torch.Tensor(inputs),1).cuda())
  else:
    batch_inputs = Variable(torch.stack(torch.Tensor(inputs),1))
  return batch_inputs, lengths_inputs
```

But when I try to run the chatbot code , it gives me this error:

> stack(): argument 'tensors' (position 1) must be tuple of Tensors, not tensor

For that reason, I fixed the function like this:

```
def variable_from_sentence(sentence):
  vec, length = indexes_from_sentence(sentence)
  inputs = [vec]
  lengths_inputs = [length]
  if hp.cuda:
    batch_inputs = torch.stack(inputs, 1).cuda()
  else:
    batch_inputs = torch.stack(inputs, 1)
  return batch_inputs, lengths_inputs
```

But it still gives me error, and the error is like this:

> TypeError: expected Tensor as element 0 in argument 0, but got list

What should I do now in this situation?

Comment: Please refrain from duplicating your own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69456032/tuple-of-tensors/69456247?noredirect=1#comment122765336_69456247). You already received an answer there but didn't wait for a follow-up on your comment. Instead, you should undelete and edit the initial post explaining what doesn't work with the provided answer(s).

Comment: @Ivan I am sorry man. I am still learning the rules of this community. Can you please explain me the solution here ?

Comment: What are the types of `vec` and `length`?

Comment: @Ivan length must be integer, and I am not sure about vec .

Comment: @Ivan I checked it. Both of them are Integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `vec` and `length` are both integers, you can use `torch.tensor` directly:

```py
def variable_from_sentence(sentence):
    vec, length = indexes_from_sentence(sentence)
    inputs = [vec]
    lengths_inputs = [length]
    if hp.cuda:
        batch_inputs = torch.tensor(inputs, device='cuda')
    else:
        batch_inputs = torch.tensor(inputs)
    return batch_inputs, lengths_inputs
```

Comment: Thanks man. Can you please provide me the solution if type of vec= list , and type of length= int ?

Comment: Then you would do `torch.tensor(vec)` and `torch.tensor([length])`.

Comment: So it will be like this:- inputs= torch.tensor(vec) and length_inputs = torch.tensor([length])  . Like this?

Comment: Indeed, `torch.tensor` expects a *list* or *tuple*.

Comment: Thanks man. I appreciate you.